# Google Direction API - Indoor directions

Tags: android, direction

I am using the Google's Android MAPs API V2 for indoor mapping in our app. It displays the indoor map correctly. Now, I am calling the Directions API to get the co-ordinates between two points to plot them on the indoor map for the way finding. However the Directions API always returns outside walking co-ordinates for two points selected within the indoor map. Is Indoor directions API only available for Google's Maps app ?

Comment: This is perhaps a better question for http://gis.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Posted there too .. Thanks